# Jira 4.4 gadget - IE9 table width

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, jira, jira-plugin

I have the next content in a Jira gadget:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
.testTable {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.testDiv {
    max-width:30px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<table class="testTable">
    <tr><td><div class="testDiv">this is looooooooo ooooooooo ooooooooooooo ooooooooo ng text</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

As you see, I would like to limit the width of a column. The code works well in the next combinations:
- FF simple html
- FF Jira all versions (using code as content of a gadget)
- IE9 simple html
- IE9 Jira 5.1 (using code as content of a gadget)

But my company uses Jira 4.4 and IE9 - this is the only combination where the copied code does NOT limit the width of column. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[IE conditional comments](http://haslayout.net/condcom)** to make different style for IE:

```
<!-- [if ie 9]>
    stuff here
<![endif]>
```

for more info check out [how to create an ie only stylesheet](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

If you need more help let me know which jira gadget are you using to display this HTML.

To limit the width of the page use `width:30px;`

that being said, try to add `width:100%;` to the stylesheet:

```
.testDiv {
    max-width:30px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This should work, try [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DNjUX/), works for me on IE9.

try to use strict html, change `<!DOCTYPE html>` to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

maybe the rule is overwritten, try :

```
max-width:30px !important;
```

if this doesn't help as well, copy the div content to http://jsfiddle.net/ and add the necessary css/js.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but do you know what to put in this specific style to limit width of column?

Comment: unfortunately the problem still exists in Jira 4.4 with IE9

Comment: Which jira gadget are you using to display this HTML?

Comment: It is my own gadget - but the whole content of the gadget is this HTML.

Comment: it didn't help unfortunately

Comment: what didn't work? did you try opening http://jsfiddle.net/DNjUX/ in your IE9 browser?

Comment: In Jira 4.4, using the copied html as content of a gadget, width is of column is not set correctly.